# Atalho para renomear, sobrepor ou substituir palavras ou variaveis iguais no Kotlin | Intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij

Como substituir todas as palavras iguais do codigo de uma vez usando Kotlin através do Intellij.

*Eu substitui a Class student por Friends e preciso mudar isso em todo o codigo*

Trocar:

```
 fun enrollStudent(courseId: String, student: Student) {
```

Por:

```
fun enrollFriend(courseId: String, friend: Friend) {
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Pressione Ctrl-Shift-R (se for MacOS se eu não me engano é Cmd+Shift+R), veja se aparece a opção `Replace in Path`, se não for esse o atalho do comando vá na opção do IDE no Keymap e veja o atalho exato, depois de abrir o Replace in Path, basta colocar os valores que deseja substituir e no outro os valor que deseja ser aplicado.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o atalho `Ctrl + Shift + R` ou `Command + Shift + R` para mudar um texto em todas as ocorrências dele no código.